# How does this call the data of the tables

Tags: oracle

So was I trying to debug some c# that pulls back some data for the website and trace the code down to calling an Oracle procedure which I found to be in the package library, but from there I could not work out how it retrieve any data.

Could someone explain what this piece of code does for me?

```
PROCEDURE PROC_GetLAWCAndCommonVariables(P_QuoteRequestID IN TB_QUOTEREQUEST.QUOTEREQUESTID%TYPE,
                                        P_CaseQuoteID    IN TB_CASEQUOTE.CASEQUOTEID%TYPE,
                                        P_POSTCODE       IN TB_STRUCTUREDADDRESS.POSTCODE%TYPE,
                                        P_UserID         IN TB_CUSTOMERINDIVIDUAL.USERID%TYPE,
                                        P_Sector         IN TB_CUSTOMERINDIVIDUAL.DEFAULTSECTOR%TYPE,
                                        P_DWSSuppID      IN TB_PRODUCTSUPPLIERLINK.SUPPID%TYPE,
                                        P_LASuppID       IN TB_PRODUCTSUPPLIERLINK.SUPPID%TYPE,
                                        O_LAWCIDsAndVariables OUT NOCOPY ref_Cursor);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only the specification of the procedure showing the parameters and whether they are accepting a value (IN) or returning a value (OUT).

The actual implementation - SQL SELECT etc - is in the private package body that you may not have the permission to see. Ask your DBA to give you a copy or grant your user view access to the package body.

Comment: Great thanks, it was my tool i didnt see a new icon for the body of the package